# AWK between 2 patterns - first occurence

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am having this example of ini file. I need to extract the names between 2 patterns Name_Z1 and OBJ=Name_Z1 and put them each on a line.

The problem is that there are more than one occurences with Name_Z1 and OBJ=Name_Z1 and i only need first occurence.

```
[Name_Z5]
random;text
Names;Jesus;Tom;Miguel
random;text
OBJ=Name_Z5

[Name_Z1]
random;text
Names;Jhon;Alex;Smith
random;text
OBJ=Name_Z1

[Name_Z2]
random;text
Names;Chris;Mara;Iordana
random;text
OBJ=Name_Z2

[Name_Z1_Phone]
random;text
Names;Bill;Stan;Mike
random;text
OBJ=Name_Z1_Phone
```

My desired output would be:

```
Jhon
Alex
Smith
```

I am currently writing a more ample script in bash and i am stuck on this. I prefer awk to do the job.

My greatly appreciation for who can help me. Thank you!

**For Wintermute solution: The [Name_Z1] part looks like this:**

```
[CAB_Z1]
READ_ONLY=false
FilterAttr=CeaseTime;blank|ObjectOfReference;contains;511047;512044;513008;593026;598326;CL5518;CL5521;CL5538;CL5612;CL5620|PerceivedSeverity;=;Critical;Major;Minor|ProbableCause;!=;HOUSE ALARM;IO DEVICE|ProblemText;contains;AIRE;ALIMENTA;BATER;CONVERTIDOR;DISTRIBUCION;FUEGO;HURTO;MAINS;MALLO;MAYOR;MENOR;PANEL;TEMP
NAME=CAB_Z1
```

And the [Name_Z1_Phone] part looks like this:

```
[CAB_Z1_FUEGO]
READ_ONLY=false
FilterAttr=CeaseTime;blank|ObjectOfReference;contains;511047;512044;513008;593026;598326;CL5518;CL5521;CL5538;CL5612;CL5620|PerceivedSeverity;=;Critical;Major;Minor|ProbableCause;!=;HOUSE ALARM;IO DEVICE|ProblemText;contains;FUEGO
NAME=CAB_Z1_FUEGO
```

The fix should be somewhere around the "|PerceivedSeverity"

Expected Output:

```
511047
512044
513008
593026
598326
CL5518
CL5521
CL5538
CL5612
CL5620
```

Comment: The ini file i am using it s very huge ~4500 lines. As far as i know awk is doing better for this kind of files. But if you have a solution, that would be great. It wouldn't hurt a combination of awk and grep. anything helps. thanks

Comment: I approve Wintermute solution. This question has finally found an answer. Thank you all and Happy new year!

Comment: New update: It doesn't seem to work in Oracle Solarin SunOs 5.10 (an old version from 2005) . I need to run the script remotely on this machine. I still need an awk solution. Thank you all

Comment: Final solution: nawk '(x+=/Z1/)&&match($0,/contains;([^|]+)/,a)&&gsub(";","\n",a[1]){print a[1];exit}' f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An (g)awk way that doesn't need a set number of fields(although i have assumed that `contains;` will always be on the line you need the names from.

```
(g)awk '(x+=/Z1/)&&match($0,/contains;([^|]+)/,a)&&gsub(";","\n",a[1]){print a[1];exit}' f
```

#### Explanation

```
(x+=/Z1/)                       - Increments x when Z1 is found. Also part of a 
                                  condition so x must exist to continue.

match($0,/contains;([^|]+)/,a)  - Matches contains; and then captures everything after 
                                  up to the |. Stores the capture in a. Again a 
                                  condition so must succeed to continue.

gsub(";","\n",a[1])             - Substitutes all the ; for newlines in the capture 
                                  group a[1].


{print a[1];exit}'              - If all conditions are met then print a[1] and exit.
```

This way should work in (m)awk

```
awk '(x+=/Z1/)&&/contains/{split($0,a,"|");y=split(a[2],b,";");for(i=3;i<=y;i++) 
      print b[i];exit}' file
```

Comment: I am getting an error: awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,

Comment: @Futur'Fusionneur Check your version of awk with `--version`. It is most likely that the match can only take two arguments in your version.

Comment: awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040

Comment: it is the stock awk that comes with ubuntu 14.04.1

Comment: @Futur'Fusionneur Yep `mawk` `match` only takes two args.

Comment: so what it is your suggestion ? i did the apt-get update and upgrade but this seems to be the latest version. Should i use nawk instead?

Comment: @Futur'Fusionneur added update, and no nawk is awful. Download gawk if you can.

Comment: At a first glance this seems to be working. thank you . i will try it in the remote machine running SunOs

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 14.04.1 and works like a charm, but of course it doesn't work on this antiquity. I can't believe big corporations still use SunOs 5.10. I am getting 
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1. I can't even figure out what version of awk is this using

Comment: P.s If you are using sun it will most likely be using `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` which is terrible, it also likely has `nawk` installed as well. Use `nawk` instead. P.P.S `bailing out` means you are using `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`. Try with nawk

Comment: which awk points to /usr/bin/awk in my case. on my way to try the nawk out

Comment: Seems promising with nawk. Need to do some more tests. Thank you a lot!!

Comment: @Futur'Fusionneur No problem, glad you got it working :)

Comment: So this solution prints output for first occurrence ? What if i need the output between another pattern containing Z1. for example HUB_Z1. should i simply modify x+=/Z1/ with x+=/HUB_Z1/? I am not very sure i understand your command

Comment: @Futur'Fusionneur Yeah just change the bit between the `/`s. Z1 is the pattern to search for, so just change that to whatever pattern you want to search for.

Comment: Coming back after 4 months. I realize i have no idea why this work, nor what it does, but it works. Can you enlight me please?: `nawk '(x+=/CAB_Z1/)&&/contains/{split($0,a,"|");y=split(a[2],b,";");for(i=3;i<=y;i++) print b[i];exit}' file.ini > filtered.db`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
sed -n '/^\[Name_Z1/,/^OBJ=Name_Z1/ { /^Names/ { s/^Names;//; s/;/\n/g; p; q } }' foo.txt
```

Explanation: Written readably, the code is

```
/^\[Name_Z1/,/^OBJ=Name_Z1/ {
  /^Names/ {
    s/^Names;//
    s/;/\n/g 
    p
    q
  }
}
```

This means: In the pattern range `/^\[Name_Z1/,/^OBJ=Name_Z1/`, for all lines that match the pattern `/^Names/`, remove the `Names;` in the beginning, then replace all remaining `;` with newlines, print the whole thing, and then quit. Since it immediately quits, it will only handle the first such line in the first such pattern range.

EDIT: The update made things a bit more complicated. I suggest

```
sed -n '/^\[CAB_Z1/,/^NAME=CAB_Z1/ { /^FilterAttr=/ { s/^.*contains;\(.*\)|PerceivedSeverity.*$/\1/; s/;/\n/g; p; q } }' foo.txt
```

The main difference is that instead of removing `^Names` from a line, the substitution

```
s/^.*contains;\(.*\)|PerceivedSeverity.*$/\1/;
```

is applied. This isolates the part between `contains;` and `|PerceivedSeverity` before continuing as before. It assumes that there is only one such part in the line. If the match is ambiguous, it will pick the one that appears last in the line.

Comment: I am getting the expected result with the example posted here. Although testing it with my ini seems not to work. I will investigate further to see what is the problem and I will come back with an answer. Thank you !

Comment: Wild hunch: Whitespace at the beginning of a line? If so, the patterns will have to be amended (removing the `^` in the pattern range, replacing it with `^\s*` in the inner condition and substitution).

Comment: Er...what exactly is the output you expect from that? Everything after the `=`, split at `|`s?

Comment: I posted the output also. I need the names of several stations between contains; and |PerceivedSeverity

Comment: I must specify ( for nu11p01n73R solution ) that i do not know the exact number of stations between the two patterns. I don't need to count them just to extract them. This ini file is updated regularly and the number of stations is variable

Comment: See edit. How many things there are between `contains;` and `|PerceivedSeverity` is not important for this, but it is important that there is only one region between a `contains;` and a `|PerceivedSeverity`. I notice that there are two `contains;` in your example, so it might be prudent to resolve possible ambiguities (perhaps by making `ObjectOfReference` part of the pattern, but I'm guessing about the structure of your data with that).

Comment: Yes there is another one next to |ProblemText. I will check your edit asap

Comment: Wow. You must be a sed God . It works as expected. All my respect to you sir. I must look more into this sed thingy to understand it. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in Oracle Solarin SunOs 5.10 (an old version from 2005) . I need to run the script remotely on this machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/\[Name_Z1\]/,/OBJ=Name_Z1$/ s/Names;//p' file.txt | tr ';' '\n'
```

That is `sed -n` to avoid printing anything not explicitly requested.  Start from Name_Z1 and finish at OBJ=Name_Z1.  Remove Names; and print the rest of the line where it occurs.  Finally, replace semicolons with newlines.

Comment: This does not restrict itself to the first occurence if there are several.

Comment: for me this outputs: Jhon
Alex
Smith
Chris
Mara
Iordana
Bill
Stan
Mike . It shows all names until last occurence of OBJ=Name_Z1

Comment: @Futur, Wintermute's answer shows how to fix that with `sed`, by using `q` to terminate early.

Answer (score 1):

Awk solution would be

```
$ awk -F";" '/Name_Z1/{f=1} f && /Names/{print $2,$3,$4} /OBJ=Name_Z1/{exit}' OFS="\n" input
Jhon
Alex
Smith
```

**OR**

```
$ awk -F";" '/Name_Z1/{f++} f==1 && /Names/{print $2,$3,$4}' OFS="\n" input
Jhon
Alex
Smith
```

---

- `-F";"` sets the field seperator as `;`
- `/Name_Z1/{f++}` matches the line with pattern `/Name_Z1/` If matched increment `{f++}`
- `f==1 && /Names/{print $2,$3,$4}` is same as `if f == 1 and maches pattern Name with line` if true, then print the the columns 2 3 and 4 (delimted by `;`)
- `OFS="\n"` sets the output filed seperator as `\n` new line

---

**EDIT**

```
$ awk -F"[;|]" '/Z1/{f++} f==1 && NF>1{for (i=5; i<15; i++)print $i}' input
511047
512044
513008
593026
598326
CL5518
CL5521
CL5538
CL5612
CL5620
```

Comment: Thank you! Your both solutions work within my example. But still it doesn't work with my ini. I will investigate some more and come back with an answer

Comment: Is the ini file exactly same as the one given in the example?

Comment: Please see the updated edit above. After the names there is "|PerceivedSeverity". I need to delete what is afterwards. Thank you!

Comment: Hah :) nice try . it works for my post but.. you count the names. I mean in my ini file there are tons of names. I didn't put them here, because there are too many. I need to select between the two patterns, without knowing the exact number of the names

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic solution for data in group of blocks.
This `awk` does not need the end tag, just the start.

```
awk -vRS= -F"\n" '/^\[Name_Z1\]/ {n=split($3,a,";");for (i=2;i<=n;i++) print a[i];exit}' file
Jhon
Alex
Smith
```

---

How it works:

```
awk -vRS= -F"\n" '      # By setting RS to nothing, one record equals one block. Then FS is set to one line as a field
/^\[Name_Z1\]/ {        # Search for block with [Name_Z1]
    n=split($3,a,";")   # Split field 3, the names and store number of fields in variable n
    for (i=2;i<=n;i++)  # Loop from second to last field
        print a[i]      # Print the fields
        exit            # Exits after first find
' file
```

---

With updated data

```
cat file
data

[CAB_Z1_FUEGO]
READ_ONLY=false
FilterAttr=CeaseTime;blank|ObjectOfReference;contains;511047;512044;513008;593026;598326;CL5518;CL5521;CL5538;CL5612;CL5620|PerceivedSeverity;=;Critical;Major;Minor|ProbableCause;!=;HOUSE ALARM;IO DEVICE|ProblemText;contains;FUEGO
NAME=CAB_Z1_FUEGO

data
```

```
awk -vRS= -F"\n" '/^\[CAB_Z1_FUEGO\]/ {split($3,a,"|");n=split(a[2],b,";");for (i=3;i<=n;i++) print b[i]}' file
511047
512044
513008
593026
598326
CL5518
CL5521
CL5538
CL5612
CL5620
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me...i used exactly your "data - to - data" file and your command and i don'get any output

Comment: @Futur'Fusionneur likely again that your version can not use `RS=` nothing.

Comment: @Futur'Fusionneur Strange.  It works for me. What `awk` do you have?  `awk --version`.  You can also try  `-v RS=""`

Comment: awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040

Comment: I did the apt-get update and upgrade. this seems to be the latest version. Is it nawk required for this?

Comment: @Futur'Fusionneur It might be a `gnu awk` thing.  Try one more `-v RS="\n\n"`.  What system are you on?

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` script will do what you want:

```
awk 's==1&&/^Names/{gsub("Names;","",$0);gsub(";","\n",$0);print}/^\[Name_Z1\]$/||/^OBJ=Name_Z1$/{s++}' inputFileName
```

In more detail:

```
s==1 && /^Names;/ {
    gsub ("Names;","",$0);
    gsub(";","\n",$0);
    print
}
/^\[Name_Z1\]$/ || /^OBJ=Name_Z1$/ {
    s++
}
```

The state `s` starts with a value of zero and is incremented whenever you find one of the two lines:

```
[Name_Z1]
OBJ=Name_Z1
```

That means, between the first set of those lines, `s` will be equal to one. That's where the other condition comes in. When `s` is one and you find a line starting with `Names;`, you do two substitutions.

The first is to get rid of the `Names;` at the front, the second is to replace all `;` semi-colon characters with a newline. Then you print it out.

The output for your given test data is, as expected:

```
Jhon
Alex
Smith
```

Comment: I do not get any result with this script when i use it in the example posted. Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: @Futur: then I suspect you've either made a mistake typing it in or there's something different about your `awk` implementation or input file. It works fine with GNU `awk` under Debian and, in fact, the output in the final paragraph is a copy'n'paste from a terminal shell, based on a file created from your test data in the question. Check for whitespace in the lines being used as markers.

Comment: Meanwhile Wintermute found the solution to this and it works perfect. This community is incredible